# I need to get information from the command oc get quotas in Openshift

Tags: openshift, jsonpath

I need to extract some information from the openshift, i am using jsonpath to do it and somenthings i already find how to do. But there are some information that i can't get from the command oc get quota -n (project name) -o json.

```
**{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "items": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "v1",
            "kind": "ResourceQuota",
            "metadata": {
                "creationTimestamp": "2019-01-14T20:15:01Z",
                "name": "",
                "namespace": "",
                "resourceVersion": "184222288",
                "selfLink": "",
                "uid": ""
            },
            "spec": {
                "hard": {
                    "limits.cpu": "8",
                    "limits.memory": "32Gi",
                    "requests.cpu": "8",
                    "requests.memory": "32Gi"
                }
            },
            "status": {
                "hard": {
                    "limits.cpu": "8",
                    "limits.memory": "32Gi",
                    "requests.cpu": "8",
                    "requests.memory": "32Gi"
                },
                "used": {
                    "limits.cpu": "4500m",
                    "limits.memory": "14848Mi",
                    "requests.cpu": "4400m",
                    "requests.memory": "14124Mi"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "kind": "List",
    "metadata": {
        "resourceVersion": "",
        "selfLink": ""
    }
}

I want the information inside spec
"spec": {
                "hard": {
                    "limits.cpu": "8",
                    "limits.memory": "32Gi",
                    "requests.cpu": "8",
                    "requests.memory": "32Gi"
                }**
```

I tried in a lot ways to get this information but none was suceeded
oc get quota -n (project name) -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"\n"}{.spec.hard.limits.cpu}'
oc get quota -n (project name) -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"\n"}{.spec.hard[limits.cpu]}'
oc get quota -n (project name) -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"\n"}{.spec.hard."limits.cpu"}'

Using the scape "\" i get some information but there some informartion that didn t return.
Command:

oc get quota -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"\n"}{.metadata.namespace}{";"}{.status.hard.limits.cpu}{";"}{.spec.hard.limits.memory}{";"}{.status.used.limits.cpu}{";"}{.spec.used.limits.memory}{";"}{.spec.used.requests.cpu}{";"}{.spec.used.requests.memory}{end}' --all-namespaces

return:

```
digitaldev;16;32Gi;5800m;;;
digitaldev;;;;;;
fastdatadev;8;64Gi;0;;;
fastdatadev;;;;;;
```

Comment: With `{range}`, you also need to specify `{end}`. Are you doing that?

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/

Comment: I put {end} and it return it
timpdv;quota-timpdv;;
timpdv;storage-timpdv;;

Didn t show any error but don t bring the values

Comment: Try with `.spec.hard.limits\.cpu`, note the "\" before the period separating `limits` and `cpu`. This is required to escape the period, since it's not actually a selector, but part of the key itself.

Comment: It worked, i never thougth that was the problem.
So simple rsrs.
Thank you, you help me a lot

Comment: It isn't perfect yet there are some information tha don't came , even with the scape

Comment: oc get quota -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{"\n"}{.metadata.namespace}{";"}{.status.hard.limits\.cpu}{";"}{.spec.hard.limits\.memory}{";"}{.status.used.limits\.cpu}{";"}{.spec.used.limits\.memory}{";"}{.spec.used.requests\.cpu}{";"}{.spec.used.requests\.memory}{end}' --all-namespaces
return
digitaldev;16;32Gi;5800m;;;
digitaldev;;;;;;
fastdatadev;8;64Gi;0;;;
fastdatadev;;;;;;
timpdv;8;32Gi;4500m;;;
timpdv1;8;32Gi;7200m;;;
timpdv1;;;;;;
timpdv2;8;32Gi;5600m;;;

Comment: The `used` key is within the `status` of your `resourcequota` (not in `spec`). As far as I can tell, @WillGordon 's solution was just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!